# Getting the status of the previous teststep in a SoapUI Groovy step

Tags: groovy, soapui, status

I have the following TestCase Set up:

```
Datasource
 Soap Request
 Groovy Script
Datasource loop
```

I would like to get the status of the SoapRequest test step using Groovy Script test step.

It can be done as show below:

```
myTestStepResult = testRunner.runTestStepByName("Soap Request")
myStatus = myTestStepResult.getStatus()
```

But I don't want to run the TestStep by script, but just using the soapui testrunner.
In a datasink test step I can use this:

```
${=testRunner.results[testRunner.results.size()-1].status}
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work in a GroovyScript TestStep

Any ideas?

Comment: Han van Oostende, you mean  do want to use hard coded step name? Please clarify otherwise?

Comment: Also, did not get - **"But I don't want to run the TestStep by script, but just using the soapui testrunner."**. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Hope this clarifies: I want to run the testcase not using the groovyscript testrunner.runTestStepByName

Comment: Messed up the last comment:

Hope this clarifies: I noticed that if I use
[Groovy Script]
myTestStepResult = testRunner.runTestStepByName("Soap Request")
myStatus = myTestStepResult.getStatus()

it will run the testStep soapRequest one time when it gets to the Soap Request step
and a second time when it gets to the Groovy Script where it calls testRunner.runTestStepByName("Soap Request")

I wanted only the status from the first call (when it runs the testcase)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run the test step without using test step name and get the status as needed. And it is assumed that the there is no change in the test step sequence i.e., `Soap Request` step is always the previous step of `Groovy Script` step, and no other step comes in between the two.

**Groovy Script:**

```groovy
log.info testRunner.runTestStep(context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex - 1]).status
```

Comment: I'm going to try that one out en report if this works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to run the test step (again), please try the following:

```
results = testRunner.getResults()
status = results.get(results.size() - 1).getStatus()
log.info status
```

After running the test case, the script log should display the status of the previous test step.

Please note that the Groovy Script test step containing the code has to be executed when running the test case. If you run just the test step, you will get the following error:

`(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)`

which is normal, because you cannot get results.size() if the list is empty.